# Webview payfort payment error restriction

Tags: android, api, android-webview, payment-gateway

[image]In my application simply booking ticket through webview and i am also check that url on android api level-19 to api-23 devices. But i am getting same issue while load payment url

```
"Sorry,but you can't make payment using this brower as its version is considered unsecure. Please use latest version of your browser or download and install latest version of free Firfox / Chrome."
```

I am search lots of but not get proper solution for this error. Also update the chrome & Firefox app , but not getting response.

For webview i am using that following code for load url :

```
URL = getArguments().getString("URL_PAYMENT");
        web_v = (WebView) viewMain.findViewById(R.id.pay_webview);
        // web_v.loadUrl(getArguments().getString("URL_PAYMENT"));
        // HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new NoSSLv3Factory());
        web_v.loadUrl(URL);
        web_v.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web_v.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        web_v.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        web_v.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web_v.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web_v.getSettings().getCacheMode();

        web_v.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
        {


            private ProgressDialog mProgress;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                if (mProgress == null) {
                    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    mProgress.show();
                }
                mProgress.setMessage("Loading ");
                if (progress == 100) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    mProgress = null;
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

Please give me actual solution for make payment successfully .

Comment: I got the right answer.Communicate with server end and also with server hosting . It removes the authentication & Ssl permission for payment in web-view.

Comment: Can you provide more details on how you solved this issue ?